# Unable change Transport type to MQTT in thingsboard device profile

Tags: mqtt, thingsboard

I am getting the following error when trying to edit the device profile transport type to MQTT

```
Can't change device profile transport type because devices referenced it!
```

This is how it looks like

[image]

I have no idea on how to go forward from this

I have tried searching online but i find no answers.

There is only one thing that i can assume that i have to do is to randomly remove devices which does not really feel like the correct way.